# Use boocamp driver on windows installer screen

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I boot my windows10 installer from USB memory stick on Mac Book Pro 2018.

Windows Installer starts correctly, but keyboard or trackpad doesn't work.

I have bluetooth mouse but it doesn't work either of course.

So I am trying to install driver before install screen starts, according to this article.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/installing-a-boot-start-driver

I copied this folder to my installer USB memory stick root .

`WindowsSupport/BootCamp/Drivers/Apple/AppleKeyboard`

then try to ,, but no button works....

```
Begin your Windows installation (run the Windows setup program). 
During the text-mode phase of the installation (at the beginning of the installation),
Windows displays a message that indicates that you can press a specific Fn key to install a boot-start driver.
```

Is there any way to solve this??

Comment: You could alway revert back to using a virtual machine to install Windows to your chosen destination.